# Why is is it F(x) in fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: integration

I am learning about the fundamental theorem of calculus at the moment. It makes perfect sense to me that $$\int_a^b f(t)\;dt=F(b)-F(a)\tag1$$

What makes me confused is this different variables x and dt in the following:

$$F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\;dt\tag2$$

So I tried to work through it and I got some idea, but I am not sure if this is correct:

I. Both (1) and (2) are actually about a function f(t)

II. In (1) we are trying to evaluate the area under f(t) over an intervall [a,b]

III. (This is where I am not sure and get confused) In (2) we are evaluating the area under f(t) over an intervall [a,x]

IV. (Even more insecured) that x of the statement III before has actually nothing to do with the often used "f(x) function". In statement (2) F(x) does not mean "a function F of x" but it is a value x for the function F(t).

Is this correct so far? So the main question is about the last one: does F(x) mean in this case "the value of x for t in F(t)" ?

Edit: To make my question more clear: What is F(x) ? I mean indefinite integrals states that when I form the antiderivative of f(t) I will receive F(t); If I then want to know the specific area under a curve between to points I fill in those values in my function F(t). How comes that [in (2)] suddenly we receive a function with a new variable? Where does the t disappears to ?

I have tried to explain my problem in three pictures, the function used is the simple one f(t)=t, so F(t)=1:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is very confusing...all those letters are just variables, real numbers. The second formula is the same as the first in case of $F(a)=0$, and $b$ was replaced by $x$. There is no real change apart from that. A function itself does not come with an argument. $F$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, meaning that $F(3)$ is a real number, $F(x)$ is a real number, $F(b)$ also is.

Comment: $$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) dt$$ is the area under the curve $f$ from point $a$ to point $x$. The reason that we have an $x$ as the upper limit of the integral is that we want to think of changing the value of $x$. So, your statement III is correct if $x \geq a$. If $x < a$, then the integral is negative the area under the curve $[x,a]$, since we think of taking the area "in the opposite direction: going from $a$ to $x$ if $x < a$" is give a negative area.

Comment: I am now not sure if the answer of Paul and both of you @Luke and user357980, are all saying the same and I am still not getting it, or if this is truly a contradiction. Is F(x) actually a very own function different from F(t), t=x ?

Comment: No, it's not, that's what I'm saying. Use whatever letter you want.

Answer (score 0):

I. They are both about a function $f$, yes. The 'name' of the variable doesn't really matter, it could be $f(x)$, $f(t)$, whatever, as long as the variable in $f(.)$ is a real-valued variable.

II. Yes. You are integrating the function $f(t)$ over the interval, $t \in (a,b)$.

III. In (2) you are defining a new function, $F(x)$. The definition for this function states that, at any given real number $x$, the value of the function $F(x)$ is equal to that interval... in other words, $F(x)$ is defined as the value obtained from integrating the function $f(t)$ over the interval $t \in (a,x)$.

IV. No. $F(x)$ is certainly a function of $x$, and $f(t)$ is certainly a function of $t$. In (2), the 'naming' of $x$ and $t$ are completely arbitrary.

You are first given the function, $f$, and are (probably) also told it's defined on some interval (at least) containing $(a,b)$. So, given any real number - whether it's $x$, $t$, $a$, $b$, $q$?, anything defined in that interval - you can compute the value of $f$ at that point, $f(x)$, $f(t)$, etc.

(1) states that the integral of $f$, when taken on the interval $(a,b)$ - the area under the curve $f(t)$ on the interval $t \in (a,b)$ - is equal to the difference between two numbers. Specifically, these two numbers are the values of some function $F$ at those points defining the interval, $a$ and $b$. From this definition alone, you do not know what $F$ is, just that some function $F$ exists and that the integral is equal to $F(b) - F(a)$.

(2) provides a definition for that function, so for any given real number $x$, you know how to find the value $F(x)$. So since $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, you can use $x=a$ and $x=b$ to find $F(a)$ and $F(b)$. The reason $x$ and $t$ are separate variables in (2) is that you're defining what the function's value $F(x)$ is for a specific $x$, but this value is computed by integrating the function $f$ over an interval of $(a,x)$, so $t$ is used as the variable of integration.

Comment: So if I decide to actually draw F(x) (say it is a simple two dimensional function): This would not be a certain point but  a very own function in which I name the axis x and y and not t ? I am simply still confused what this F(x) is : Since I can not imagine of how an area under a curve of a function of t becomes a function of x somehow. If I would to the indefinite integral - I would never consider to suddenly switch variables. I mean in (1) I use the indefinite integral put some values in and receive a result. What is (2) even for?